# MySQL Workbench - Is Schema the same thing that Database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to set the Database name for a php code.

But I have a doubt, because in Workbench I have a MySQL schema called ******. Is it equivalent to a Database or is a diferent thing? I'm asking that because I haven't found any explicit reference to DB creating in Workbench.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, in MySQL, schema and database are synonyms.  This even extends to the syntax:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo;
DROP SCHEMA foo;

CREATE SCHEMA bar;
DROP DATABASE bar;
```

Both a schema and a database is basically a namespace for tables.

In some other implementations of SQL, the terms database and schema are used differently.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better. +1