# Getting an MySQL syntax error and don't know why

Tags: mysql, database

Im trying to copy the data from the title and content columns in my articles table from a database into the wp_title and wp_content columns from the wp_posts column from a different database by using this command.

```
INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.dbo.wp_posts ('wp_title', 'wp_content')
SELECT 'title', 'content' FROM seetheuniverse.dbo.articles;
```

and this is the error I am getting and do not know why.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '.wp_posts ('wp_title', 'wp_content') SELECT
'title', 'content' FROM seetheuniver' at line 1
```

Comment: It looks like you may be using single quotes when you should be using backticks (or nothing)

Comment: The followed syntax is db_name.table_name. So wp_seetheuniverse.wp_posts would suffice

Comment: Is it wp_seetheuniverse or seetheuniverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.dbo.wp_posts ...
```

You're using a three-part qualified table name like Microsoft SQL Server.

In Microsoft SQL Server, there's a hierarchy of `[database].[schema].[table]`.

MySQL has one fewer levels to the hierarchy. In MySQL, database and schema are the same thing. The terms are [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149455/mysql-workbench-is-schema-the-same-thing-that-database/13149489#13149489) in MySQL.

I would guess that your database (aka schema) is `wp_seetheuniverse`. That looks like a wordpress database (schema). The `dbo` schema is a customary schema name in Microsoft SQL Server, not in MySQL.

To confirm, try this statement in the MySQL client:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

I expect you can get your code to work if you

```
INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.wp_posts ...
```

And similarly change other table references so they are `[database].[table]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query:

INSERT INTO dbo.wp_posts (wp_title,wp_content)
SELECT title,content FROM dbo.articles;

Where dbo is database name and wp_posts and articles are tables.